# How to do one-to-one mapping with composite key in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have three tables. A student can register for multiple courses.

**Student**
RollNumber    Integer, StudentName   String

**Course**
CourseID       Integer, CourseName     String

**StudentCourses**
RollNumber    Integer, CourseID      Integer, AllotedRoom   Integer

**Student.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="myPackage.Student" table="STUDENT">
        <id name="ROLLNUMBER" type="integer">
            <column name="ROLLNUMBER" />
        </id>

        <property name="STUDENTNAME" type="string">
            <column name="STUDENTNAME"/>
        </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Course.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="myPackage.Course" table="COURSE">
        <id name="COURSEID" type="integer">
            <column name="COURSEID" />
        </id>

        <property name="COURSENAME" type="string">
            <column name="COURSENAME"/>
        </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**StudentCourses.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="myPackage.StudentCourses" table="STUDENTCOURSES">
        <composite-id name="STUDENTCOURSES_pk" class="myPackage.STUDENTCOURSES_PK">
             <key-property name="STUDENTID" column="STUDENTID"/>
             <key-property name="COURSEID" column="COURSEID"/>
        </composite-id>

        <property name="ALLOTEDROOM" type="integer">
            <column name="ALLOTEDROOM"/>
        </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

For any record that is selected in StudentCourses table, I want to get student name as well as 
course name. How should my mapping files look like for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a many-to-one in your studentcourses you can specify the linked class.
So that would be

```
<many-to-one name="Student"
                column="studentid"
                update="false" insert="false"/>
```

In you Java studentcourse class you can specify the the Student object and retrieve the name with `studentcourse.student.studentname` in your query.
BTW StudentCourse is typically a class so you may want to change that name.